# How do I create an instance of this tagged union? Compiler errors about deleted constructor

Tags: c++

Here's my tagged union:

```
struct UniformVariant
{
    enum class UNIFORM_TYPE {FLOAT, INT32, VEC2, VEC3, VEC4, MAT4} type;
    union
    {
        float f;
        int i;
        glm::vec2 v2;
        glm::vec3 v3;
        glm::vec4 v4;
        glm::mat4 m4;
    } value;
};
```

If I try to use it like so:

```
void some_function()
{
    UniformVariant v;
    some_other_function(v);
}
```

I get a compilation error `use of deleted function 'UniformVariant::UniformVariant()'`

It further says that it was implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed. So I've tried adding a constructor to the `UniformVariant`

```
UniformVariant() : value(0.0f), type(UNIFORM_TYPE::FLOAT) { };
```

But similar issues. I believe it has to do with the inclusion of class types in the union; but I can't figure out the syntax to use this correctly.

Comment: Try `boost::variant`. It already did this better.

Comment: I think value(0.0) is wrong. Try value.f(0.0). Besides did you try just add UniformVariant() {} in the struct?

Comment: @Brahim `value.f(0.0)` is a syntax error, and the latter doesn't work as `value` needs its own constructor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a note in [class.union]:

> If any non-static data member
>   of a union has a non-trivial default constructor (12.1), copy constructor (12.8), move constructor (12.8),
>   copy assignment operator (12.8), move assignment operator (12.8), or destructor (12.4), the corresponding
>   member function of the union must be user-provided or it will be implicitly deleted (8.4.3) for the union.

One of the types in that union has a non-trivial default constructor, so you can't default-construct the union. Consider this simpler reproduction:

```
struct X {
    X() { }  
};

struct Y {
    union {
        float f;
        X x;
    } value;
};

int main()
{
    Y y;
}
```

`X` has a non-trivial default constructor, so `Y::Y()` is implicitly deleted because the anonymous union default constructor is implicitly deleted.

However, you can just provide your own default constructor for that union:

```
union U {
    U() : f(0.f) { }

    float f;
    X x;
} value;
```

And now the example compiles.

However, if you're just implementing your own tagged union, I would highly recommend using [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/variant.html). It's quite useful and solves exactly this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'm not using Boost.Variant because I'm a hobbyist programmer and would rather implement it myself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your current union is that it does not specify which member should initially be active.

C++11 does have a feature called *anonymous union* in which no member is active initially, and you activate each one as needed. This feature is essential for implementing a Variant-like object as you are trying to do, if there were no types in the list with non-trivial constructors.

However your union is not anonymous because it has a named instance `value`.

If a non-anonymous union contains any member with a non-trivial constructor (such as your `glm` classes), then that union *must* have a constructor which initializes exactly one of the members.  (Even providing a *brace-or-equal-initializer* instead is not sufficient).

---

Another option for you, besides Barry's fine suggestion, is to switch to using the anonymous union:

```
union
{
    float f;
    int i;
    glm::vec2 v2;
    glm::vec3 v3;
    glm::vec4 v4;
    glm::mat4 m4;
};
// ^^^^^ no name
```

When this happens, `f`, `i`, `v2` etc. are "promoted" up to be names at the level of `UniformVariant`. You can now write:

```
UniformVariant v;
v.i = 1;
```

To explain the initialization again: when a struct contains an anonymous union, it actually does not initialize any of the members. You must manually construct and destruct a member when you are using it.

For primitive types like `int` you can just activate them by assigning to them, and no deactivation is needed. But for class types you must use placement-new and destructor calls, for example:

```
new(&v2) glm::vec2(...args...);
```

and when you are done with that member:

```
v2.~vec2();
```

To avoid mistakes, you probably want to make the union be in the `private` section and give `X` member functions for setting the active member.